# Can we make it easy to select all text within a code block?

Tags: feature-request

I was reading the answers to the following question: [Freezing/Fixing the Top Header Row of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307135/freezing-fixing-the-top-header-row-of-a-table)

There are many code samples that contain a complete HTML document.  For my purposes, I want to copy this text into an editor, save as an HTML file, and then open it in the browser.

It would make it easier if there were something like a button next to the code block that I could click on to select/copy all the text inside the code block so that I don't have to select it manually.

Even better, it would be great if there were some way to make it so that I could click a button next to an HTML sample and have it render in a new browser window, but I do recognize that this has security implications?

Can we make it easier to select the text in large code blocks?